# Duvida tabela Usuario e tabela Amigo

Tags: java, sql

Eae galera, preciso de ajuda, eu sou principiante no java, e estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade onde vai ser uma mini rede social, no começo vamos fazer cadastro de usuario, dentro da classe beans, usuario recebe um ListaAmigos estou com uma duvida.

minha pergunta, como eu vou relacionar isso no DAO e se preciso adicionar algum dado na tabela USUARIO_AMIGO com status etc ???

Alguém pode me dar um exemplo.

Tabelas no banco USUARIO e a outra AMIGO_USUARIO.

```
             Tabela USUARIO

+-----------+------------------+----------+----------------+
| CD_LOGIN  | NOME_DE_USUARIO  |  SENHA   | EMAIL_USUARIO  |
+-----------+------------------+----------+----------------+
|       1   |      test        |   test   |       test     |
|       2   |      test        |   test   |       test     |
+---------+----------+----------+--------------------------+

              Tabela AMIGO_USUARIO

+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| CD_AMIGO  | EMAIL_USUARIO | EMAIL_USUARIO2  |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1   |      test     |      test       |    
|       2   |      test     |      test       |           
+---------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Tá usando Hibernate?

Comment: isso é um framework certo? não posso usar nenhum tipo de framework, regra do trabalho :/

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ter na tabela associativa, o status. E outro ponto importante, use código do usuário e não o email. Se algum dia o usuário quiser mudar o email, você terá problemas.

```
Tabela AMIGO_USUARIO

+-----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| CD_AMIGO  | CD_USUARIO1   | CD_USUARIO2     |   status    |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
|       1   |      test     |      test       |    1        |
|       2   |      test     |      test       |    0        |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Na DAO você não relaciona os dados, apenas faz o acesso a elas. Você terá o relacionamento na Model, ela representará a entidade do banco na sua aplicação. Ex:

```
public class Amizade {
        public Amigo amigo1;
        public Amigo amigo2;
        int status;
    }
    // Essa abaixo é a DAO
    public class AmizadeRepository{
       public ArrayList<Amizade> fetchAll(){
        // fazer a consulta e retornar a lista
       }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado cara pela dica, mas vc sabe como eu associaria isso na minha classe DAO? você tem algum exemplo?

Comment: E vou precisar criar uma outra tabela de associação no banco ?

Comment: Exatamente, editei o post para você ter uma ideia melhor. O model é sempre uma tabela no banco.

Comment: então vou precisar criar uma classe amigos?, porque ate então tinha chamado ela dentro da classe usuario.

private ArrayList<Usuario> amigos;

Comment: Pode trocar Amigo por Usuario, foi só uma opção de nome.

Comment: sim, tranquilo, mas vc fez a "Amizade", eu teria que fazer outra classe? porque só fiz a Usuário e a usuario não recebe o "status" só a tabela "usuario_amigo". não se se vc vai entender rs

Comment: Amizade = usuario_amigo e Amigo = Usuario. Eu só mudei a nomenclatura, mas o conceito é o mesmo.

Comment: a entendi, agora uma duvida que surgiu cara, vou precisar criar uma tabela no banco pra associar tabela amigo + tabela usuario ?

Comment: tipo: UsuarioXAmigo

Comment: Essa tabela você já criou, é a AMIGO_USUARIO. Não sei se te confundi muito com a mudança de nomenclatura..

Comment: Um pouco rs, desculpa cara estou praticamente começando agora

Comment: @Murilo Azevedo já que ele não pode usar hibernate, então a outra "ferramenta" é JPA?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Comment: jsp + servlet + dao + bo assim que estamos aprendendo rs